# How to add CSS to elements after form submission using JS

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently creating a meme generator app where the user can submit an image, as well as top and bottom text. I want to make it so that after form submission, the text is added onto the image and styled using CSS. I have already tried adding a class to the elements and adding css to it but that does not work. Here is my code:

JS

```
let form = document.querySelector('#meme-form');
let img = document.querySelector('#img');
let topTxt = document.querySelector('#top-txt');
let bottomTxt = document.querySelector('#bottom-txt');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let memePic = document.createElement('img');
    //create the divs for the memes
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    form.appendChild(newDiv);
    topTxt.classList.add('top')
    bottomTxt.classList.add('bottom')
    memePic.src = img.value;
    newDiv.append(memePic, topTxt.value, bottomTxt.value);

    //set the textbox inputs equal to nothing
    img.value = '';
    topTxt.value = '';
    bottomTxt.value= '';   

})
```

CSS

```
div {  
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.top{
    color: blue;
}
#bottom-txt {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <form action="" id="meme-form">
        <label for="image">img url here</label>
        <input id="img" type="url"><br>
        <label for="top-text">top text here</label>
        <input id="top-txt" type="text"><br>
        <label for="bottom-text">bottom text here</label>
        <input id="bottom-txt" type="text"><br>
        <input type="submit"><br>
    </form>
    <script src="meme.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to fix up some of `logic` how the elements are being `appended` after `form` is submitted.

For that you need to `div` after your `form` which will hold you `results` and then order your `element` to be displayed. I have also added a line `hr` to have `separator` between each `results` displayed.

You can `style` your element the way you would like them to be - i have added some basic `CSS` to show some styling and an actual `img` url for demo purpose only.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
let form = document.querySelector('#meme-form');
let img = document.querySelector('#img');
let topTxt = document.querySelector('#top-txt');
let bottomTxt = document.querySelector('#bottom-txt');
let results = document.querySelector('.meme-results');


form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let memePic = document.createElement('img');
  var hrLine = document.createElement('hr');

  //create the divs for the memes
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');

  let topText = document.createElement('span');
  let bttomText = document.createElement('span');

  //Top text
  topText.classList.add('top')
  topText.textContent = topTxt.value

  //Img
  memePic.src = img.value;
  results.appendChild(topText);
  results.append(memePic);

  //bottom text
  bttomText.classList.add('bottom')
  bttomText.textContent = bottomTxt.value
  results.append(bttomText);
  results.append(hrLine);


  //set the textbox inputs equal to nothing
  //img.value = '';
  topTxt.value = '';
  bottomTxt.value = '';

})
```

```css
.meme-results {
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.top, #top-txt {
  color: blue;
}

.bottom, #bottom-txt  {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form action="" id="meme-form">
    <label for="image">img url here</label>
    <input id="img" type="url" value="https://via.placeholder.com/150"><br>
    <label for="top-text">top text here</label>
    <input id="top-txt" type="text"><br>
    <label for="bottom-text">bottom text here</label>
    <input id="bottom-txt" type="text"><br>
    <input type="submit"><br>
  </form>
  <div class="meme-results"></div>
  <script src="meme.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```